# plex media server keeps asking me to install plex media server

Tags: plex

I've installed plex media server, but it keeps asking me to install plex media server on its web interface:

[image]

Apparently, it doesn't find some other component of itself, because it says "Looking for servers..." in the top left.

What is it looking for and what might be preventing it from finding its other component?

Comment: If I download the suggested file, I get exactly the same .deb file that I already installed using sudo dpkg -i plex.....deb

Answer (score 3):

Instead of the IP 1.1.1.14 you have to use localhost as hostname in the browser, even when connecting locally:

```
http://localhost:32400/web
```

Answer (score 0):

Just had this issue myself, this page was the first result I found but the above answers did not help, so here's what I did to fix it...which has happened before, I think EVERY FREAKING TIME IT UPDATES, but I never remember the fix...so maybe I'll find my own post next time :)

The issue, in my case, is that it consistently wipes out the preferences file at /var/lib/plexmediaserver/Library/Application Support/Plex Media Server/Preferences.xml. In my case, the issue is the "allowedNetworks" property...I have a few different subnets, but one that I have NEVER had is 192.168.2.0/24 -- which is what it decided to set that property to for some incomprehensible reason. Once I corrected that it started working again, although as you might expect it seems to have wiped all of my server configurations...my library is still there but it's once again defaulted to trying to force streaming media on me and hiding my own library behind a maze of menu options... (really getting sick of this attitude from Plex lately....)